# Cannot make an array of class

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
private:
    int idNum;
    string name;
public:
    Person(const int, const string);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Person&);
};
Person::Person(const int id, const string nm)
{
    idNum = id;
    name = nm;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Person& p)
{
    out << p.name << p.idNum;
    return out;
}
ostream& personDisplay(ostream& s)
{
    cout.setf(ios::left);
    cout.width(12);
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    Person p[MAX];
    int id;
    string name;
    int x = 0;
    const int QUIT = 0;
    cout << "Enter an ID number or " << QUIT << " to quit ";
    cin >> id;
    while(id != QUIT && x < MAX)
    {
        cout << " Enter name ";
        cin >> name;
        p[x] = Person(name, id);
        ++x;
        cout << "Enter an ID number or " << QUIT << " to quit ";
        cin >> id;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < count; ++x)
    {
        cout << personDisplay << p[x];
        if(x % 2 == 1)
            cout << endl;
        cout << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program defines a person class which includes an
   overloaded insertion operator.
    Also included is a personDisplay manipulator
    that sets a field size for the name.
    The program gets up to 10 entries, then displays
    the results in two columns. The error is

> main.cpp:41:15: error: no matching function for call to 'Person::Person()'
>       Person p[MAX];

How do I fix this error?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Students learning to code often have to use arrays because the teacher wants them to be able to, but I'll explain a more C++ approach that's easier to get right and more powerful... if you can't use it now you'll want to soon.

user4581301 gives a good explanation of why and how to add a default constructor that lets you use your array.  Downsides after that fix are  that you've got these default-initialised array members hanging around that don't actually have proper ids and names in them, have to maintain `count` yourself to know which ones are "in use", and still have a `MAX` amount of `Person`s your program can cope with.

A better fix is to remove the array and use:

```
std::vector<Person> p;
```

(You'll need to `#include <vector>` atop your program to do this.)

Then you can change the line `p[x] = Person(name, id);` to:

```
p.emplace_back(name, id);
```

And that will add a `Person` to the "back" of the `vector`.  You can remove the `count` variable and its uses: if you want to know how many `Person`s are in the `vector` you can call `p.size()`.

A final benefit is that you can iterate over the `vector` with:

```
for (const Person& person : p)
{
    cout << ...etc...
```

There are lots of other, smaller improvements that can be made to the code, culminating in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

class Person
{
  public:
    Person(int id, std::string name);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);
  private:
    int idNum_;
    std::string name_;
};

Person::Person(int idNum, std::string name)
  : idNum_{idNum}, name_{std::move(name)}
{ }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Person& p)
{
    return out << p.name_ << ' ' << p.idNum_;
}

std::ostream& personDisplay(std::ostream& s)
{
    s.setf(std::ios::left);
    s.width(12);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    const int QUIT = 0;
    const int MAX = 10;
    std::vector<Person> persons;
    int id;
    std::string name;

    while (persons.size() < MAX &&
           std::cout << "Enter an ID number or " << QUIT << " to quit " &&
           std::cin >> id &&
           id != QUIT)
    {
        std::cout << " Enter name ";
        std::cin >> name;
        persons.emplace_back(id, std::move(name));
    }

    int personsPrinted = 0;
    for (const auto& person : persons)
    {
        std::cout << personDisplay << person;
        if (++personsPrinted % 2 == 0)
            std::cout << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "   ";
    }
    if (persons.size() % 2) std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(Code available to run/edit on [coliru.stackedcrooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cd632a865760009))

Answer (score 1):

```
Person p[MAX];
```

requires a default constructor to default-initialize all of the elements of `p`. Unfortunately defining

```
Person(const int, const string);
```

stopped the compiler from automatically generating a default constructor.

You could initialize all of the elements of `p` with uniform initialization, but there doesn't look to be much point to that since you're just going to load the array up as the user provides input.

Let's tell the compiler that we still want a default constructor.

```
Person() = default;
```

or

```
Person() {}
```

if compiling for an older C++ standard.

Addendum: Tony Delroy's answer is dead right. If you are allowed to use a `std::vector`, use it. If not, this is probably the sanest of inferior options.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing an array of Person objects requires a default constructor (one which takes no parameters).  You have not provided one.

Comment: To be slightly more accurate, a default constructor is one that can be _called_ without any parameters. Fun things: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/letter-the-third/

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
Person p[MAX];
```

You don't just declare the datatype but also try to create the MAX number of Person objects, using a constructor with no parameters - which is absent in the Person class here. Remember, when you create any constructor for a class, the compiler does not automatically create the default constructor for you.

You should either declare a Person constructor with no parameters, or you may want to work with an array of Person pointers.

Comment: I recommend against the use of pointers unless you are wiling to scope the pointers with a smart pointer, but even then it's a bit dodgy. Better to use a `std::vector`